# android - Showing variable changes

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Ok - I know there has got to be a simple solution to this but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Programming a very basic android activity to simply iterate through 0-99. I have a textview that I want to display the count. What happens is that it simply stays blank until the end and then shows the ending count (99).

Not sure if a textview is the right way to display or what the answer is. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your code? Is this for a timer or something? If all you're doing is running a for loop on the UI thread, that won't work.

Comment: Show us your code and we can help. But my guess would be that you are using a `for loop` and not calling `setText()` on your `TextView` until you have iterated completely through the loop

Comment: ...or you're doing it in onCreate().  Where you do this is as important as how you do it..

Comment: it (the code) is just as CommonsWare is suggesting - and I can understand the answer he/she provided - back in a min - testing something

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the stackoverflow community.

Comment: I was hoping to keep it 'real time' rather than fixed intervals. I am sending info to a server for sync and wanted to show user the status of how many items had been sent from phone to server out of total items - Even with going to server I can't get it to show on screen the current position of items sent versus totals. It simply waits until all items have been sent and shows 'done'

Comment: I am eventually going to put it as background thread and will show user in a small area on screen what is going on in the background so they know what's going on

Comment: For what you describe in comments you definitely should be using some kind of background processing. I don't like AsyncTasks, but you may try it. It has convinient method publishProgress.

Anyway it's better to add such informations to the question. You didn't want to achieve what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks. I think I did achieve what I was looking for

Comment: Thanks. I think I did achieve what I was looking for but yes I didn't ask the right thing - but I guess I didn't know what to ask for. I think next time I'll just spend more time laying out the exact situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using code like this in onCreate (where `number` is defined as a field):

```
textView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        number++;
        textView.setText("counting: " + number);
        if (number < 100) {
            textView.postDelayed(this, 50);
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit**: code was edited as View classes have post and postDelayed, which propagates call to Handler instance they have internally.

You need to read a bit about [Handler class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

**Warning**: this code leaks Activity for the time of approximatelly 5 seconds and should not be used directly in production code. You need to remove `Runnable` from the message queue at the appropriate time (maybe in onDestroy, but it depends on your needs).

[View.removeCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for anti-memory-leak.

Comment: Note that `postDelayed()` is also on `View`, so you do not need to bother with creating a `Handler`.

Comment: I tried this (code from MaciejGorski) and it works just fine - with the comments from CommonsWare, do we still worry about the leak issues since we arent using the Handler class?

Comment: We do, Handler is still used internally - in the View-derived class. But if you are doing some kind of blocking processing like you describe in comments under your question, I would recommend using Service (or at least AsyncTask). You won't have nice user experience if you connect with the server on UI thread.

Comment: @KeithPittner: "do we still worry about the leak issues since we arent using the Handler class?" --  in this simplified scenario, yes. Five seconds is not usually a problem, and the activity might be around for other reasons anyway. Only if the user pressed BACK would a leak occur. If you wanted to, you could call `removeCallbacks()` on your `TextView`, passing in the `Runnable`, from the `onDestroy()` method to remove the `postDelayed()` loop. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/PostDelayed

Comment: [PostDelayedDemo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Threads/PostDelayed/src/com/commonsware/android/post/PostDelayedDemo.java) is a nice example, although there is (another) leak there related to Toast on Android 2.x. ;)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your `onCreate()` has code like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<100;i++) {
  tv.setText(String.valueOf(i));
  Thread.sleep(100); // or something to delay for a bit
}
```

That will give you the output that you are describing.

As with many GUI frameworks, Android's UI is event-driven. Calling `setText()` does not update the screen. Rather, it puts a message on a queue, asking for the screen to be updated. That queue is processed by the main application thread... the same thread that is calling `onCreate()` in the first place. Hence, what you are doing is queuing up 100 `setText()` calls, none of which will be processed until your loop is complete. Applying the 100 of them takes very little time, giving the visual result of only seeing the last change.

Comment: What is the solution then? would putting that code in an AsycTask work?

Comment: @dberm22 AsyncTask is not needed for non-blocking operations.

Comment: @MaciejGórski So you would have to use a handler?

Comment: @dberm22 Yes, but be careful as MessageQueue (which Message/Runnable along with Handler is sent to) will not let it go until it is finished processing or removed by your code, leading to memory leaks and potentially crashes.

Answer (score 0):

User a timer scheduled at a fixed rate. Increment a counter every second. Set the text on the UI thread. cancel the timer when required.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView _tv;
Timer _t;
int _count=0;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    _tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textView1 );
    _t = new Timer();
    _tv.setText(""+_count);
    _t.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                _count++;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
                 {
                  public void run() 
                  { 

                      _tv.setText(""+_count);
                      if(_count==99)
                      {
                          _t.cancel();
                      }
                 }
                 });
            }
        }, 1000, 1000 ); 


    }
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    _t.cancel();
}  
 }
```

Comment: Using `postDelayed()`, as in MaciejGórski's answer, would be more efficient, as it avoids the extra thread.

Comment: @CommonsWare agreed. This is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Use a countdown timer, in below code, onTick() will get called every second, here you can display/update your number each second.
set interval according to your need. Its in mili seconds.

public class TimerActivity extends Activity {

```
private final long startTime = 100 * 1000;
private final long interval = 1 * 1000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
    countDownTimer.start();

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        text.setText("Time's up!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        text.setText(100 - millisUntilFinished/1000);
    }
}
```

}